# Subversion (SVN) equivalant to Visual Source Safe (VSS) "Share"

Tags: svn, visual-sourcesafe, share

I have a scenario in my project where I need to share a single file between multiple projects in the same solution. Back in my Visual Source Safe days (Shudder), I'd use the "Share" option to allow me to make changes to this file in any of the locations. Then once it was checked in I could guarantee that the other locations will get the update.

[image]

I'm trying to do this in Subversion but I can't seem to find the option anywhere. I do know about svn:externals however I'm only interested in sharing a single file between multiple locations.

Does anyone know how to do this in Subversion?

Thanks

**Edit**

In the end i decided to use the sharing capabilities in visual studio. It works exactly like the share used to work in Visual Source safe. I.e. I only have to maintain 1 file and both are updated.

To do this you goto Add Existing Item >> Then CLick Add as Link from the top down bottom right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SVN 1.6 has added support for single [file externals](http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.6_releasenotes.html#file-externals)

Comment: Any idea's on how you actually use this new functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps these responses are useful: [Sharing files in SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249787/sharing-files-in-svn)